# Excel - File summary details?

Tags: excel, summary

I'll do my best here but I'm sure I'm not choosing the best terms.

I inherited a large Excel file at work. It's been passed around for nearly 5 years and had multiple authors who have added data, functions, worksheets, macros, etc. The file is used by the department to handle scheduling metrics. 
The current file has 28 worksheets - some of which have 60+ columns, a few thousand rows, sumif formulas that take up 3 full lines in the function preview box! The current file takes 25+ minutes to crunch the numbers!

Anyway, I've been tasked with recreating a more streamlined version from scratch. When I'm done, I'd like to show some objective data on how I streamlined it.

Is there some way to quickly get a summary of an Excel file that details how much "data"/"data types" it contains? For example, how many cells contain numbers, how many contain text, how many contain formulas, how many named ranges, hope many different Excel functions are used, how many cells are dependent on VBA code, etc etc.

Each of these is doable in small scale, but I'm estimating there's a hundred thousand cells containg some form of the above data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this link: https://www.spreadsheet1.com/formula-auditor-download.html not exactly all you want to find out, but may get you started

Comment: This is maybe not what you are looking for, but if I understand you correctly, the issue is the 25+ minutes for the whole thing to be calculated. Maybe, instead of re-writing the whole thing, you might search for a bottleneck which might increase the performance of your Excel-file? (Which opens a new question "When Excel is doing something, is there a way to find out how many time it spends doing what exactly?" (profiling within Excel, does that even exist?)